# How can I store the web push notification settings after the login in database

Tags: laravel

I want to send web push notification on the browser. I used [this](https://github.com/Minishlink/web-push-php-example) tutorial to 
 send the notification. This is working fine and show the details.

[image]

```
{
"endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/ftB1OYn5bJY:APA91bGNcquGDcUXr29JiVV5Zos4Vi7FzmZ_wJQMITEXt8FlVBRBtgrPdLnPR6GALtnCOe9RNPP1cmC_bkv9D1BE1o6_-0cMXQsodpPoRCeOP5EDt6EwqK0ys36MbCi3HNTWf7ZcItVi",
"expirationTime":null,
"keys":{"p256dh":"BLJQqNovnlJ28d5xteX8whwdby6l0BYLvC_iyNtY2nO7YXQSI-EOvdOs1LXy8F_EuH2MZi0FU_HoCO-5GRQYYVQ",
"auth":"tDcEgiy5M5tJ3_vXuuQ9uw"}
}
```

but I want to integrate with my Laravel API.

After the user login, I want to save the `endpoint`, `public key`, and `auth`
to the database.

**Login Controller**

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');
    // return $credentials;

    $response = array(
        'status' => 'Failed',
        'msg' => '',
        'is_success' => false,
        'data' => ''
    );
    try {
        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {

            $response["msg"] = "Wrong Username or Password";
            $response["status"] = "Failed";
            $response["is_success"] = false;
        } else {
            if (Auth::user()->is_active == 0) {
                $response["msg"] = "Your account has not been activated";
                $response["status"] = "Failed";
                $response["is_success"] = false;
            } else {

                $data = array();
                $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
                $data['id'] = $user->id;
                $data['fname'] = $user->fname;
                $data['lname'] = $user->lname;
                $data['email'] = $user->email;
                $data['username'] = $user->username;
                $response["msg"] = "Login Successfully";
                $response["status"] = "Success";
                $response["data"] = compact('token');
                $response["user"] = Auth::user();    
            }
        }
    } catch (\Exception $th) {
        $response["msg"] = $th->getMessage();;
        $response["status"] = "Failed";
        $response["is_success"] = false;
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this, is to make another model for that data, a one to one relationship between user model and push notification data model. Make a controller for CRUD operations on this new model, and just have another http call from the front end to store the data.

Comment: How can I send the console.log data to that model? Because this is with javascript too.

Comment: Seems that you need to learn what a RESTful HTTP API is and how to make that in laravel. Also, seems that you don't know how to make http requests from front end javascript in order to consume the API built above.

Comment: You can start learning here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: I am new to Laravel. that's why I  am asking